# Homestead and MySQL Problems

Tags: mysql, homestead

I'm using homestead and trying login to my mysql database via phpmyadmin. I have used same settings couple years already.
Yesterday I started working and I run the command `homestead up` - but this time everything seemed a bit different than usually. For example, `vagrant insecure key detected` and then vagrant automatically replace that with a newly generated keypair - okay, thats not bad, and I guess thats completely fine.

After that its stop and start `nginx` and `php5-fpm` nine times and then comes `==> default: mysql: 
==> default: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
==> default: Please use --connect-expired-password option or invoke mysql in interactive mode.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.`

Okay, well I logged in `homestead ssh` and then `mysql -u homestead -p password` and set the new password. No errors thrown. Great.

Then I tried to log in my database `phpmyadmin.app` with the `homestead` username and `new password` but.. for some reason my databases are disappeared.

Well... after great Google search session I noticed when I write `mysql> select * from mysql.user;` command, there is two homestead users. First one is under `0.0.0.0` ip and second is under `%` - I'm pretty sure that this causes my problem one way or another, because the homestead user which uses `%` is made same day when this problem first time occurred.

Or.. I'm completely wrong direction and the problem causes for different reason(s). Whatever the case, I'm here to ask some help from a bit smarter guys than me.

Should I remove the second homestead user, or what would you suggest?

I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I removed ´%´ homestead user and also I changed ´0.0.0.0´ host to ´localhost´ and tried to reset password but no matter what I do its denied the access. fffffss This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

First see [my mysql answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106953/539149) for a related issue.

For these kinds of problems with Laravel Homestead, I recommend throwing away and reinitializing the Vagrant box.  Homestead is just a sandbox (as long as you back up your client machine data, there is no harm in rebuilding the sandbox).

**First, back up any MySQL databases or other client machine information with a tool like mysqldump or Sequel Pro, as it will be lost when your box is re-provisioned.**

Then:

```
# from host machine
cd ~/Homestead
vagrant destroy
vagrant box prune
vagrant up --provision

# if still seeing MySQL errors during provisioning, do the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46106953/539149 or:
vagrant ssh

# log into mysql (for Homestead your password is likely "secret")
mysql -h localhost -u homestead -p

SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('secret');

-- A) set password to never expire:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;

-- or B) to change password as well:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password', 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;

-- quit mysql
quit

# exit back to host shell
exit

vagrant up --provision
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the password? It sounds like in the process, you probably created a new user which didn't have the proper permissions. This explains why you weren't able to see the databases when connecting as that user.

Then, you went and deleted that user, which would have put you back where you started, except you also changed the host from 0.0.0.0 to 'localhost'. I'm not familiar with using the 0.0.0.0 syntax in this location, but presumably it means all TCP hosts just like when used in my.cnf for bind-address. Normally I use '%', but I hesitate to suggest that because if 0.0.0.0 was working, I wouldn't mess with it. But anyway, 'localhost' is different from '%' or any other TCP connection; localhost specifically refers to socket connections, whereas the others refer to TCP connections. Probably your applications are using the tcp protocol, and you just removed permissions for that user (by telling MySQL to only allow connections over the socket protocol).

I suggest any of these solutions:

- Revert the existing user to the 0.0.0.0 hostname
- Change the existing user's hostname to %
- Add a new user, but give proper permissions to the database that user needs to access
- Tell your applications to access MySQL using the socket protocol rather than tcp networking (depending on your exact system configuration).

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem for many days and it really drives me crazy. Dont know why, my Homestead and its credential to access to mysql was fine until recently. Basically I just create a new user and stop using homestead as user.

If you can still ssh to it and sudo su, you can try this.

1) vagrant ssh

2) sudo su

3) mysql -u root -p ( when you are as super user, mysql wont ask you password)

4) Then simply set a new user.

> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

then

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';

5) Then, login to phpmyadmin using the new user.